# Mapeando usuários ativos e desconectando se exceder 3 usuários simultaneos em java

Tags: java, session, hashmap, wowza, linkedhashmap

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia mapear os usuários que se conectam baseados nos seus id's únicos e sessão id para que quando houver mais de 3 sessões para esse id, os usuários que se conectaram primeiro sejam removidos do HashMap e assim por diante.

Exemplo:

```
UserID:1 Sessão:1989448
UserID:1 Sessão:2848484
UserID:1 Sessão:84848
```

Quando uma nova conexão fosse feita, se existissem 3 conexões, a mais antiga seria desconectada/removida do hashmap ficando como abaixo por exemplo.

```
UserID:1 Sessão:2848484
UserID:1 Sessão:84848
UserID:1 Sessão:4848880
```

Código java:

```
public void onHTTPCupertinoStreamingSessionCreate(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino httpSession) {
    String User_Session = httpSession.getSessionId();
    String Client_ID = httpSession.getProperties().getPropertyStr("sql_client_id");
    //adiciona ao hashmap o Client_ID e o User_Session.
}

public void onHTTPCupertinoStreamingSessionDestroy(IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession) {
    String User_Session = httpSession.getSessionId();
    //remove do hashmap o Client_ID baseado na sessão User_Session
}

public void KillSession(int SessionId){
    IApplicationInstance Instance = applicationInstance;
    IHTTPStreamerSession sessions = Instance.getHTTPStreamerSessions().get(SessionId);
    sessions.rejectSession();
}

//Checa e remove do hash map se houver mais de 3 conexões para o mesmo Client_ID invocando o KillSession
```

O Client_ID é o id do usuário no banco de dados, o User_Session é a sessão unica no wowza gerada para cada conexão, essa sessão não tem valores iguais, ou seja, se um mesmo Client_ID conectar mais de uma vez, esse valor vai ser diferente para cada uma de suas sessões.

O Client_ID  no hashmap serve para contar quantas conexões o usuário em questão tem, e fazer o que se é discutido aqui.

Ou seja, basicamente a minha dificuldade é montar o hashmap, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: De onde você tira esse `session id`?

Comment: O session id é o id único da sessão atual do cliente no wowza, grosseiramente dizendo é como a sua identidade, e serve para muitas coisas, pois ele é único para cada conexão ativa. É obtido atraves do comando: `String Session_ID = httpSession.getSessionId();`  não coloquei o `IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession` porque não era muito relevante, ou seja, são duas Strings a do Client_ID e a do Session_ID que devem ficar no hashmap, o Client_ID é obtido do SQL e o Session_ID do wowza, quando uma nova conexão for feita pelo mesmo Client_ID, os valores mais antigos devem ser removidos do hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, vamos supor que você tenha uma classe `IdUsuario` que representa (como o nome diz), o id de algum usuário. Essa classe deve ser imutável e deve implementar os métodos `equals` e `hashCode` adequadamente. Se preferir, pode usar `Long` ou `String` no lugar, mas vou partir do pressuposto que o id acabará sendo algo mais complicado. Vou assumir que há uma classe `IdSession` nos mesmos moldes que encapsule o `session id` do wowza.

Um exemplo bem simples dessas classes seria isso:

```
public final class IdUsuario {
    private final String id;

    public IdUsuario(String id) {
        if (id == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof IdUsuario) && id.equals(((IdUsuario) obj).id);
    }
}
```

```
public final class IdSession {
    private final String id;

    public IdSession(String id) {
        if (id == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof IdSession) && id.equals(((IdSession) obj).id);
    }
}
```

Entretanto, se você quiser enriquecer essas classes com mais dados que você considere pertinente para identificar usuários e sessões, sinta-se a vontade.

Da mesma forma, vou assumir que os dados da sessão estão armazenados em uma classe ou interface `SessaoUsuario` que tenha esses métodos:

```
void notificarDesconexao();
void notificarConexao();
```

Assim sendo, você usa o padrão singleton para ter um repositório de sessões:

```
public class RepositorioSessoes {

    private static final int SESSOES_POR_USUARIO = 3;
    private static final RepositorioSessoes REPOSITORIO = new RepositorioSessoes();

    public static RepositorioSessoes instance() {
        return REPOSITORIO;
    }

    private final Map<IdUsuario, GrupoSessaoUsuario> grupos;

    private RepositorioSessoes() {
        sessoes = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public void conectar(
           IdUsuario idUsuario,
           IdSession idSession,
           BiFunction<IdUsuario, IdSession, SessaoUsuario> criaSessoes)
    {
       GrupoSessaoUsuario grupo = sessoes.computeIfAbsent(idUsuario, k -> new GrupoSessaoUsuario(k, SESSOES_POR_USUARIO));
       grupo.conectar(idSession, criaSessoes);
    }

    public void desconectarTodos(IdUsuario id) {
        GrupoSessaoUsuario grupo = sessoes.get(id);
        if (grupo == null) return;
        grupo.limpar();
        sessoes.remove(id);
    }

    private static class GrupoSessaoUsuario {
        private final IdUsuario idUsuario;
        private final int limite;
        private final Map<IdSession, SessaoUsuario> sessoes;

        public GrupoSessaoUsuario(IdUsuario idUsuario, int limite) {
            this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
            this.sessoes = new LinkedHashMap<>(limite);
            this.limite = limite;
        }

        public synchronized void conectar(
            IdSession idSession,
            BiFunction<IdUsuario, IdSession, SessaoUsuario> criaSessoes)
        {
            SessaoUsuario novaSessao = null;
            if (sessoes.containsKey(idSession)) {
                novaSessao = sessoes.remove(idSession);
            } else if (sessoes.size() >= limite) {
                Iterator<SessaoUsuario> it = sessoes.values().iterator();
                it.next().notificarDesconexao();
                it.remove();
            }
            if (novaSessao != null) novaSessao = criaSessoes.apply(idUsuario, idSession);
            sessoes.put(idSession, novaSessao);
            novaSessao.notificarConexao();
        }

        public synchronized void limpar() {
           for (SessaoUsuario s : sessoes.values()) {
               s.notificarDesconexao();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Sempre que o usuário conectar, você chama o método `conectar(IdUsuario, IdSession, BiFunction<IdUsuario, IdSession, SessaoUsuario>)`. Quando quiser dar o *kill*, chame o `desconectarTodos(IdUsuario)`. A abordagem aqui usada não é a de criar-se uma thread para controlar isso, e sim a de criar-se um objeto para controlar isso.

O método `conectar` é um pouquinho complicadinho de se usar por causa desse `BiFunction`, mas não é muito difícil não. Vamos supor que você tem em algum lugar uma função para criar uma `SessaoUsuario` assim:

```
public SessaoUsuario criarSessao(IdUsuario idUsuario, IdSession idSession) {
    ...
}
```

Então, você chamaria ele assim:

```
IdUsuario idUsuario = ...;
IdSession idSession = ...;
RepositorioSessoes.instance().conectar(idUsuario, idSession, this::criarSessao);
```

Ou então, você pode usar um construtor de `SessaoUsuario`:

```
public SessaoUsuario(IdUsuario idUsuario, IdSession idSession) {
    ...
}
```

Então, você chamaria ele assim:

```
IdUsuario idUsuario = ...;
IdSession idSession = ...;
RepositorioSessoes.instance().conectar(idUsuario, idSession, SessaoUsuario::new);
```

A classe `RepositorioSessoes` se incumbe em chamar quando pertinente e necessário, os métodos `notificarConexao` e `notificarDesconexao`.

A classe interna `GrupoSessaoUsuario` (que não é pública) gerencia as três sessões do usuário. Quando ele se conecta com uma sessão já existente, a mesma vai para o fim da fila (pois neste caso, essa se torna a mais nova). Se já houverem três sessões, ele vai remover a mais antiga.

Os métodos da classe `GrupoSessaoUsuario` são sincronizados para garantir que duas conexões simultâneas executas em thread diferentes não acabem bagunçando o estado interno `GrupoSessaoUsuario`. Essa sincronização ocorre no objeto `GrupoSessaoUsuario`, e vez que cada usuário deve ter uma e apenas uma instância deste objeto, então diferentes threads de usuários diferentes não irão competir por esse objeto, apenas threads de um mesmo usuário o farão. O único lugar em que esse objeto é criado, é na chamada ao [método `computeIfAbsent` do `ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) que tem garantia de ser atômico, e portanto haverá apenas uma única instância desse para cada `IdUsuario` e portanto um para cada usuário.

Esta classe deve funcionar tanto no caso em que você nunca reutilize ids de sessão quanto no caso de você os reutilizar sempre.

A implementação acima pode ser simplificada um pouco no caso de o seu `IdSession` ser implementado de uma forma que seja possível chegar-se ao `IdUsuario` diretamente (por exemplo, se `IdSession` tiver um campo com referência ao `IdUsuario`).

Comment: Não existem sessões idênticas, cada nova sessão é unica, mesmo para o mesmo Client_ID. O que pode se repetir é o Client_ID.

Comment: @Florida Editei a resposta.